# Problem with printing out on POS printer in python

Tags: python, thermal-printer, point-of-sale, escpos

I can't figure out a way to print on a POS machine(EPSON TM-T20III).

I have tried creating a text file and then printing it. It works, but I have no control over alignments, font type, font size, or specifying printer(at least 2 printers will be connected). So I came across this Python library called Escpos. Here is my code using that library:

```
from escpos.printer import Usb

#######(vendor id, device id, 0, profile)
p = Usb(0x6&398681A4, 0x1, 0, profile="TM-T20III")
p.text("Hello World\n")
p.cut()
```

This code can't find my printer:

`error: USBNotFoundError("Device not found or cable not plugged in.")`

I'm suspecting that I may have the wrong details for the vendor id and device id. I got them by:

- Open the **Device Manager** by right-clicking on the **Start** button and selecting **Device Manager**.
- Expand the **Printers** section.
- Right-click on your printer and select **Properties**.
- Click on the **Details** tab.
- In the **Property** drop-down list, select **Hardware IDs**.
- The vendor ID and product ID will be listed in the **Value** column.

  - This is what I'm getting: usbprint\epsontm-t20iii2dac
- In the **Property** drop-down list, select **Device instance path**.

  - This is what I'm getting: USBPRINT\EPSONTM-T20III\6&398681A4&1&USB002. Accoding to chartGPT the Vendor id is 0x6&398681A4 and the product id is 0x1

Note: Network connection if off the table for me. Thank you for helping

Comment: Please check the USB ID with the utility distributed by EPSON, not with the device manager of the OS. [TM-T20III Utility](https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=single_soft&cid=6176&pcat=3&pid=6146)